# Non-Differentiability of Brownian motion path

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, random-walk

I am trying to understand why Brownian Motion is not differentiable.

Here we are tossing a coin n-times.

So we form a sample space $ \Omega $.

Each of the paths are represented by ω = ω1 ω2 ω3…. ωn

In all likely situation, sample space will include the following two paths

- outcomes of the tosses are either purely Heads-H or purely Tails Then

these two paths can be written as
o   (omega) ω =HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH…n times
o   (omega) ω = TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT..ntimes

In my understanding both the above cases the paths/Brownian motion is a straight line. In other words, not a zig-zag

In my view, the above two omegas are differentiable as both are straight lines. So two of the random walks/paths in the Omega $ \omega $ are differentiable.

I have come across in several texts and videos that Brownian motion is not differentiable. I agree that except for the above two paths remaining are not differentiable.

The clarification I seek is whether Brownian Motion is differentiable at each time period
•   For the above two paths at every/any point
•   for the remaining paths in the omega (sample space other than the above two)
This might sound naïve, why is it important to be differentiable at every step.

Coming from a non-math background, I have built my skills to this stage with the help of PhD student. But there is always the possibility my fundamentals may not be perfect or complete.

Kindly guide/help me.

Thank you

Comment: You have left off how your coin-flipping relates to Brownian motion.  If it's as a result of Donsker's invariance principle, then you've left off the time scaling that would make this path a vertical line.  If it's as some result of sampling, then it has nothing to do with differentiability.  ----- As a final point, when we say something like "Brownian motion is nowhere differentiable", we technically mean "Almost every path of Brownian motion is nowhere differentiable".  That is, the set of paths on which Brownian motion is differentiable somewhere has probability zero.

Comment: A random walk (i.e. a sequence of heads and tails) is not a Brownian motion.  A Brownian motion is a stochastic process which is continuous in time, which can be realized as the *limit* of random walks.  Even if you regard a straight line as a Brownian motion (i.e. the path traced out by a specific particle moving according to a Brownian motion), the probability that a particle will trace out such a path is zero (under suitable constructions of "probability"), hence one might rephrase the statement as "the path of a Brownian motion is nowhere differentiable with probability 1".

Comment: A suggestion: check the defition of differentiability from a formal point of view. The argument "the above two omegas are differentiable as both are straight lines", makes little sense.

Comment: @Math-fun I don't think one really needs to check the definition of differentiability to conclude a straight line is differentiable

Comment: Brian Moehring/Xander Henderson, Bulls eye, nothing short of it. Precisely I got the clarification I was looking for. No Book, no video made these specific statements/ clarifications. For a person doing self study, this help is fantastic. It was worth every bit of my time drafting this question. Thank you all.

Comment: @user6247850 maybe I don't under the concept in this framework myself. Thank you very much for the hint. What does it mean that a "certain $\omega$", as is referred to by OP, is a straight line which is the differentiable [with respect to what]?

Comment: @Math-fun I agree that it's certainly not a precise statement, so perhaps it only makes sense to me because I'm familiar with the context.  I interpreted it to be an informal description of thinking about Brownian motion as a random variable on the sample space $C([0,\infty))$, in which case it makes sense to ask whether a certain $\omega \in C([0,\infty))$ is differentiable.  Although there is a rather large gap between the coin toss space they described and the path space I believe they were thinking of (as mentioned in the first two comments), so my interpretation might be too charitable.

Comment: @user6247850 thank you very much for the explanation. I still think OP will benefit from looking at a formal defition of differentiability since it becomes possible to see if the process satisfies certain conditions so as to be tagged differentiable or not.

Comment: Just for clarification, what does OP refer to? Just curious is it referring to the person/original post.

Comment: @KD007 OP stands for "Original Poster", you in this case  :)

Comment: @Math-fun I agree with user6247850, in this case it seems that the definition of differentiability is somehow marginal. In fact if we use the canonical construction of the Brownian motion, i.e. seeing each trajectory as an element of the Wiener space $C_0([0,1])$ then the important part is the "almost surely" non differentiability. Of course there are differentiable trajectories in the Wiener space, the important bit is that this subspace has 0 Wiener measure

Comment: Thank you Yuval Peres for your guidance/input. I am yet to purchase the book and read it.
Just in case, you have not seen my other posts. I have raised another post on Partial averaging. Can you please let me know if your book covers a discussion/example on Partial averaging?
I am happy to purchase both the books and go through and understand how each presents/explains a topic. 
My request is more out of curiosity and priortiisation.
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The proof of a.s. nondifferentiability of Brownian motion is explained in Theorem 1.30, page 21 of the book [1].  The theorem was first proved by Paley, Wiener and Zygmund in [PWZ33], but the
proof in the book is due to Dvoretzky, Erdos and Kakutani [DEK61].

[1] Mörters, Peter, and Yuval Peres. Brownian motion. Vol. 30. Cambridge University Press, 2010.
https://yuvalperes.com/brownian-motion/